# How should I use type map[string]interface {} in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to retrieve data from api. When I get the data from api:

```
result, _ := s.GetCases() // get cases via api
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result.Records[0]["Cases"]))
```

It shows the type of result.Records[0]["Cases"] is map[string]interface {}

However, apparently I can't directly use this one as a map. Since:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result.Records[0]["Cases"]["Id"]))
```

This will cause compiler error:

> invalid operation: cannot index result.Records[0]["Cases"] (map index
> expression of type interface{})

May I know how should I use this type in golang?

Comment: If you can, it's probably better to parse the API response directly into an appropriate data structure (for example with [`json.Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) into a slice of structs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is of type `interface{}`, and based on the output of reflection, that interface has a `map[string]interface{}` value in it. So, you have to get the actual value stored in the interface using a type assertion:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result.Records[0]["Cases"].(map[string]interface{})["Id"]))
```